# Meteor.users.find() not retrieving all users on the server side (Working well on Client side)

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am working on a Meteor project and I wanted to check if all users email ids are verified or not. But when I call Meteor.users.find() it's only showing few records but not all.

I know Publish/Subscribe mechanism and its working well for all client display purposes. But my requirement is within the server and somehow I am not able to fetch all users.

Below are code snippets:

**imports/api/users/methods.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
  'getAllUserDetails'() {
    console.log("syam kumar testing on methods. js" , first ) ; 
    console.log("syam kumar testing on methods. js" , second ) ; 
   // return Meteor.users.find({"_id" : "iHtE2ojtowSi9xWGP"}).fetch(); 
    return Meteor.users.find().fetch(); 
  }
});
```

**imports/api/users/emailVerification.js**

```
 Meteor.call('getAllUserDetails' ,  (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log("Error Message " , err);
            } else {
                console.log("User results " , res);
            }
          });
```

**Output**
Only 2 records its fetching but My DB contains 9 users.

Any suggestions on how to fix this ??

Comment: Would you please try applying `return Meteor.users.find().fetch(); ` inside `main/server.js`? I'm suspecting that the method code is running on the client side and thus it's only fetching what's available in the minimongo. Better yet please share a mini-sample of you application on Github. Thanks!

Comment: @HarryAdel sure I will try adding that and let you know about the result. Thanks for the quick reply.